# How can I cross-compile to the Raspberry Pi using Clang/LLVM?

Tags: cross-compilation, clang, llvm

I would like to cross-compile C-family languages (C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++) to the Raspberry Pi using Clang and LLVM on a build computer of a different architecture.  How may I do this?

Comment: If the idea is to build your own software from source code (as opposed to building well-known packages from source code and targeting the ARM processor), then checking out something like [this](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-Cross-compiling-guide.html) will be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Just completed my article, [Cross compilation for Raspberry from Sierra](https://dyatkovskiy.com/2018/11/04/173/), about exactly this thing. Under Mac OS Sierra though. But for clang it matters a little.

In this article I have shared experience (which costed me some days of suffering). Hope it will be useful.
In short, all you have to do is to specify rootfs and target triple:

```
path/to/clang --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --sysroot=/some/path/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot my-happy-program.c  -fuse-ld=lld
```

I added `-fuse-ld=lld` option, because otherwise clang will try to lookup legacy binutils.

Comment: Where did you get the sysroot?

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/) article and it seems to work fine for trivial programs (console/string/math stuff, not many optimization flags). I used ver 1.19 of crosstool-ng on a x86-64 laptop running [ZenWalk](http://www.zenwalk.org/) 7.0

There also seems to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973020/cross-compilation-for-raspberry-pi-in-gcc-where-to-start) post over at SO, which might be helpful (haven't fully read thru it yet).

Comment: The OP asked for 'Clang and LLVM'